# Add numeration to each column in align environment

Tags: equations, align, labels

So this is my code:

```
\begin{align}
s &= \frac{u + v}{2}t & v^2 &= u^2 + 2as \\
v &= u + at & s &= vt - \frac{at^2}{2} \\
s &= ut + \frac{at^2}{2}
\end{align}
```

and it shows up like this:

[image]

but I need it to look like this:

[image]

preferably with each equation labeled so I can reference it.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably easiest to use two separate align environments inside side by side parboxes, though there might be other ways with fancier packages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\parbox[t]{0.4\linewidth}{%
\begin{align}
s &= \frac{u + v}{2}t  \\
v &= u + at &  \\
s &= ut + \frac{at^2}{2}
\end{align}
}\hfill
\parbox[t]{0.4\linewidth}{%
\begin{align}
v^2 &= u^2 + 2as \\
s &= vt - \frac{at^2}{2} 
\end{align}
}
\end{document}
```

[image: side by side align environments]

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer!

Answer (score 1):

Use an align environment in each of two minipages:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
    \begin{align}
    s &= \frac{u + v}{2}t\\[1ex]
    v &= u + at \\[1ex]
    s &= ut + \frac{at^2}{2}
    \end{align}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
    \begin{align}
    v^2 &= u^2 + 2as \\[1ex]
    s &= vt - \frac{at^2}{2}
    \end{align}
    \end{minipage}

    \end{document}
```

[image]